# How to remove qemu-native package to reduce build time

Tags: yocto

As i'm new to YOCTO build system.Thanks in advance for helping with this.

Recently i try to build a local YOCTO image which is totally does not need to support qemu, but when i build my image such as core-image-minimal, the bitbake server would still bitbake qemu-native package which will cost me lots of time. What i want is to remove this qemu-native package from my whole build process. How can i do it? 
I have tried to set ENABLE_BINARY_LOCALE_GENERATION = "0" in my build/conf/local.conf but it does not work.

Could somebody help me with this question?

Comment: If you use sstate-cache system, it will be only build qemu-native one time, so first build is time consuming but not the others.

Comment: Thanks, so doest this mean it's not possible to remove the package? Do you know is there any macros i can control to enable or disable the qemu-native?

Comment: Which machine do you use ? you can grep your entire Yocto sources for `qemu-native`, but it probably comes from `EXTRA_IMAGEDEPENDS` variable, so `EXTRA_IMAGEDEPENDS_remove = "qemu-native"` could work.